# casting problem from base pointer to derived

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

I have the following class architecture:

```
class A{
  public:
      A() {}
      virtual ~A() {}
      void printA() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};
class B{
  public:
      B() {}
      virtual ~B() {}
      void printB() { cout << "B" << endl; }
};
class C : public A{
    public:
        C() : A() {}
        virtual ~C() {}
        void printC() { cout << "C" << endl; }
};
class D : public B{
    public:
        D() : B() {}
        virtual ~D() {}
        void printD() { cout << "D" << endl; }
};
class P: public C, public D{
    public:
        P() : C(), D() {}
        ~P() {}
        void printP() { cout << "P" << endl; }
};
```

The problem is the fact that in Visual Studio some casts fail, but in an online compiler everything works fine. I will better explain the problem in code:

```
    A* pObject= new P(); // let s say I have this instance of type P referenced by an A type pointer
    dynamic_cast<P*>(pObject)->printP(); // works fine in both VS and online compiler, as expected
    dynamic_cast<D*>(pObject)->printD(); // THIS IS THE PROBLEM, in Visual Studio cast returns nullptr, but in online compiler works fine.
    return 0;
}
```

Do you know any solution / reason for this behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: the tag is already removed, but fwiw you have no diamond problem in your code. `P` inherits each base only once

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I did not say anything about having a diamond problem. I DO NOT have a diamond problem. The problem is with casting. Please read again my question. There is nothing about a diamond problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo that is an example. Copy paste it in your compiler and try it.

Comment: no need to panic. I did read your question and I also read the tags you used. The "diamond problem" tag was there but has been removed in the meanwhile

Comment: ups sorry it was a different user who added and removed the tag, that explains the confusion :)

Comment: @anonymous my object is of type P and P is derived from C,D. C is derived from A. Do you see the relation now?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yup, sorry about that. I was a bit hasty, quickly rolled-back my mistake, but left confusion in my wake. Lesson learnt...

Comment: It also works with my Linux gcc compiler, didn't test in windows as I don't have that system, Visual Studio uses MSVC witch has it's own libraries, that can be the source of the problem. It still puzzles me why you would write such a code.

Comment: Did you disable RTTI in your Visual Studio project configuration, by any chance?

Comment: @Theodor Badea I can not reproduce using Visual C++ 2019 Community.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow do you have any particular settings?

Comment: @TheodorBadea The option like The C++ Standard is set to default. The same result if to use the preliminary version of the language.

Comment: @TheodorBadea I also cannot reproduce any errors when running the provided code in an otherwise fresh/empty VS 2019 project (but that doesn't necessarily mean the code is legal). Please [edit] the question to add whatever command line flags are necessary to reproduce the issue. You might e.g. copy-paste `Project properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line` and possibly `Project properties -> Linker -> Command Line`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof and VladfromMoscow I get this on VisualStudio Enterprise 2017, but the toolset is v110.  If I disable RTTI other parts of code will be messed up.

Comment: Your code is correct according to both [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) (it is called "side-cast" here) and [msvc docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dynamic-cast-operator?view=vs-2019) (it is called cross-cast here). Must be some compiler problem (according to number of questions about MSVC in SO, it is quite common)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and it was foolish and caused by my lack of attention. I have to admit, the class architecture wasn't mine and somewhere on the derivation line there was a protected inheritance about I had no idea, thus dynamic_cast was failing(strange behaviour from the compiler, because in that certain file where I tried to cast it was not complaining about this inaccessible base class, but in another file it did and I managed to find the problem).